# how to overlay a background color on image in a div onhover

Tags: javascript, html, css

```css
#overlay{
  display:none;
  position:relative;
  background-color:rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
  top:0;
  left:0;
  z-index:0;
}
#main{
  
  min-height:100px;
  border:1px solid;
}
#main:hover #overlay{
  display:block;
}
```

```html
<div id="main">
  <div id="overlay"></div>
  this is something
</div>
```

I am trying to show a backgorund color on hover of the div and i have image in div instead of text in real code

Answer (score 1):

You can use `#main:hover:after` for the overlay. Try this.

```css
#main{
  min-height: 100px;
  border:1px solid;
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
}

#main:hover:after{
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%; 
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  background-color:rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
}
```

```html
<div id="main">
  <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/640x360">
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `position:absolute`, `height:100%` & `width:100%`

```css
#overlay{
  display:none;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  z-index: 1;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
#main{
  position:relative;
  min-height:100px;
  border:1px solid;
}
#main:hover #overlay{
  display:block;
}
```

```html
<div id="main">
  <div id="overlay"></div>
  this is something
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

give `position:relative` to `#main` and add the below style to `#overlay` id:

```
#overlay {
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    z-index: 1;
    bottom: 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```css
    #overlay{
      display:none;
     position:absolute;
      content:'';
      left:0;
      right:0;
      bottom:0;
      top:0;
      background-color:rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
    }
    #main{
      
      min-height:100px;
      border:1px solid;
      position:relative;
    }
    #main:hover #overlay{
      display:block;
    
    }
```

```html
<div id="main">
  <div id="overlay"></div>
  this is something
</div>
<!-- begin snippet: js hide: false console: true babel: false -->
```